# How do I create x amount of Tasks which is dependence of for example the list.Count?

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, task, console-application

It is just a test part of my code:

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                guns_data[0].Fire(pairs[0, 0], pairs[0, 1]);
            }); 
var task2 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            guns_data[1].Fire(pairs[0, 1], pairs[0, 0]);
        });
```

- (pairs) is a 2 dimensional array and contains my "players" datas (name, healt, armor...)
- (guns_data) is a list and contains my guns values and the .fire is a shooting method

---

1. I would like to create x amout of this task1,task2....taskx.
2. After that i have to waitall this tasks.

---

I know this is not the correct index because it is just a test part.
I am a begginer programer.

---

Could you help me with an example or otherway?

Comment: What do you want to solve? Why do you want to run each `Fire` method call as a separate Task?

Comment: They are x differnt pepople and they have to shoot each other in the same time. It is like a Free For All Shoot game

Comment: Is the underlying data structure thread-safe? Modifying the same resource from multiple threads requires extra care and coordination.

Comment: Your name is very Hungarian, do you speek in hungary? Otherwhise I just jump in this Task and I try to understand how it works but I have a clue how it is works I am just very begginer in this area, I don't know is it thread-safe.

Comment: Yes, I'm Hungarian but I don't know how does it relate to your question. In order to be able to help you determine whether or not the data structure (and its operations) is thread-safe please share with use the definition of `guns_data`, `pairs` and the `Fire` method. Please amend your question to include all the necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
Task[] tasks =
    guns_data
        .Select(gd => Task.Run(() => gd.Fire(pairs[0, 0], pairs[0, 1])))
        .ToArray();
        
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

I don't know how to get the indices for `pairs` correct as you didn't specify that in the question. This should help though.

Comment: I tried it and work but not as this way as I want. If I running this the gd.Fire() not use the Thread.Sleep(value) method int its block.
For example this: Thread.Sleep(Sepeed_fire);

Maybe it works if I use Task.Factory?

Comment: @user14554081 - You really need to show all of your code. It's not great to tell me what doesn't work that's not in your original question.